# Sublime text, how to auto-import implemented interface methods

Tags: php, sublimetext2, code-completion

I'm just trying to find out how can I auto-import methods of an implemented interface.

Example:

```
//LoaderInterface.php
interface LoaderInterface
{
    public function load($endpoint);
}

//myLoader.php
class myLoader implements LoaderInterface
```

and here after writing `implements LoaderInterface` I would use some command to ends up with

```
//myLoader.php
class myLoader implements LoaderInterface
{
    public function load($endpoint)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I've tried `sublimeCodeIntel` but it seems to me that is not possible, or am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I couldn't find something helpful, I've now decided to try to write my first plugin. At my first experience in Python.

Just in case someone could use it or help me improve this plugin.

> https://github.com/ilpaijin/Sublime-Text-2-AutoimportSignature-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

There is a way in sublime_text

---

1. go to tool
2. new snippet

---

> copy and pest these code `*save*` as whatever  name You want

---

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[


interface ${1:LoaderInterface}
{
    public function ${2:load($endpoint);}
}

//myLoader.php
class myLoader implements ${3:LoaderInterface}


]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>loader</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.php - variable.other.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

**Note:**

1. You can call Your snippte by typing `loader` in beet been `<?php ?>` tag   . 1 More thing to remember most save Your file as `.php`
2. if you want to `call` Your snippet by Typing `other Key Word` You can put that keyword in beet-been `<tabTrigger>**keyword**</tabTrigger>`

Comment: this answer would be much more useful if you showed the full text of the new snippet, indicated where it should be saved, and most importantly explained what exactly you're trying to do. The OP is trying to auto-import methods, not write boilerplate code, which is what your answer does.